# Aligning a list by a changing value

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, string-formatting

I have my script doing the following for the headers of the text file:

```
file.write("{:50} {:50} {:50}\n".format("Name", "Count", "Price"))
```

Then a function is called through multiple threads that write out a list:

```
file.write("{:50}{:50}{:50}".format(*map(str, input)).strip()+ "\n")
```

This gets the formatting close to the header but they all seem to be off by a bit, i'm assuming it has to do with the variable length of the contents of the list. But I'm not sure how to change the 50's in the list to make it align correctly.

My output looks like this currently:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Problem has been fixed.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance is caused by your inputs containing extra whitespace after, pushing the line lengths past the fifty characters.

You need to strip the *inputs*, not the `str.format()` output:

```
file.write("{:50}{:50}{:50}\n".format(*(str(i).strip() for i in input)))
```

Next, open your file in a *fixed-width font*. Your text is not aligning because different letters take up different widths; `m` is wider than `i`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that the strip was on the format output but this is still giving weird results.

http://i.imgur.com/FDxPfpk.png

Comment: @chernandez7: that's because you are using a proportional font to display the text. Pick a fixed-width font like Consolas or Courier.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Thank you for the help.